# Does Windows 7's "Virtual Manager" require a VT/HT enabled machine to configure VHD?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

Does Windows 7's feature "Virtual Manager" require a VT/HT enabled machine to configure VHD?

Comment: I have not seen a feature "virtual manager" can you provide any more info?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 you create virtual hard disks with Disk Manager. As I understand this, there is no CPU requirement for this (or for the ability to boot the system from a VHD). This functionality is native to Windows 7.

Running virtual machines (including XP Mode) with Windows 7's Virtual PC does require VT-X support in the CPU (or the AMD equivalent). If this enforced in the Virtual PC installer then the requirement applies to configuring virtual machines, if it is only enforced on running a guest instance you might be able to configure a virtual machine on a system without hardware support (but this be, at best, rarely useful).

Comment: This is no longer true, the VT-X requirement has been removed from XP Mode and other Virtual Machines. That update is the "step 4" from [the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) for XP mode. The update was also included in SP1 so if you have that you already have the ability to use it without VT-X

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think Virtual PC requires hardware virtualization to work, based on a completely unscientific test of installing it, then disabling VT.